# How can I convert an Apple IMA4 CAF file recorded with AVAudioRecorder to a WAV file using Core Audio Converter Services?

Tags: iphone, wav, avaudiorecorder, caf, ima4

Note: I am an audio noob, so please forgive me if I say the wrong thing!

I need to convert Apple IMA4 CAF audio files recorded with AVAudioRecorder to WAV files **from within my app**. The sample rate needs to be retained.

My app needs to support 3.x, so I cannot use AVAssetReader/Writer. I notice that when using AVAudioRecorder to record a Linear PCM WAV file directly, the CPU is always being used (probably due to lack of hardware encoding support) even when no audio is being recorded, so this is not an option either. The idea is that I can record in IMA4 because it uses 0% CPU when doing nothing, and then convert the output file to WAV.

[Core Audio Converter Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioConverterServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) has caught my eye but I just cannot figure out how to use it properly, so if anyone has used it previously, could you please share information/code on what I need to do to convert CAF files to WAV files?